# Gur Aryeh, King and Nation

Tags: malchut-royalty, maharal

The *Maharal* in *Gur Aryeh al HaTorah* says, אם עם אין כאן מלך אין כאן - *If there is no nation, there is no king.* כי אין מלך בלא עם *Because there can be no king without a nation.*

Does anyone know where in the *Gur Aryeh* this is located?

Comment: I didn't downvote, though I imagine that whoever did may have had [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2099/5323) on his mind.....

Comment: It is more than that, I think. This is being asked twice in two questions. Where does Maharal say X? Where does Baal Shem Tov say X? For the same X. When will it end? With this stackexchange into a site for thousands of repetitive questions on topic X, where each source, A, B ... says X? ps i didn't downvote either.

Comment: @joshwaxman The only thing is the X is slightly different. I'm upvoting

Answer (score 2):

As brought [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42856&st=&pgnum=67&hilite=) footnote 10, this statement, or something like it, appears several times in the writings of the Maharal. None of them is attributed to *Gur Aryeh*, which is his commentary on Rashi. The specific language you are quoting is in *Drush Al HaTorah* [page 27](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_14198_26.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. However, you mean Derashos Maharal, Drush Al HaTorah, page 27.

Comment: In what paragraph of Nesiv Ha'Teshuvah does the Maharal say this?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah, look at where footnote 10 is in the main text (on the right hand column in the top section at the link). It is the two lines leading up to it.

Comment: Thank you. I should have paid attention to what you wrote.